# SharePoint Online : Publishing Pages : problems with Ribbon and Page Content Field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, publishing-site, ribbon, publishing-page

I've got a big problem with Publishing Pages :
On a Site Collection, a "publication portal" type.
On every site which is a Publication site, in the Pages Library, i have got two different bugs in every page i create, with standard Sharepoint Content Types and standard Sharepoint Page layout.

**Step 1 :** Pages Library, in the ribbon, click on the arrow near "New Document" icon. I select "Article Page" (Sharepoint Standard Content Type), give it a name and select "(Article Page) : body only".

[image: Step 1 - 1st image]
[image: Step1 - 2nd image]

**Step2 :** When the page is created, it is extracted. I click on it, then click on "Modify" and enter several lorem ipsum lines in the body.
Then save it and publish it.

[image: Step 2 - 1st image]
[image: Step 2 - 2nd image]

So far, everything works fine.

---

**Bug #1 :**
On the page (which is published,not yet extracted), when clicking on "Site actions" (gear icon, upper right)=> "Modify Page",

[image: Bug 01 - Modify page]

I have a message popping up, saying "You need to check out this page to modify it. Do you want to check it out?" I choose "Yes".
Then the first mess happens : I can't modify the Page Content field : It is not clickable, and strangely, my ribbon doesn't show the tabs "Text Format" and "Insert".

[image: Bug 01 - Content field not modifyable]

So, i decide to cancel the check out.

---

**Bug #2 :**
On my Page Library, my article page is published, and not yet checked out.
I select it, and then go to the Page tab in ribbon and click on "check out".
Then, i click on my page title to see it. On the page, i click (like for the precedent bug) on "Site actions" => Modify.
My ribbon displays the good tabs, but freezes, and becomes grey, therefore i can't control any format of my content. But there is more, i can't modify the text in my Page Content field. (like in bug #1) 
[image: Bug 02 : ribbon freezes]

---

**Is there anyone here who does have the same problem ?**

**Do you know where it could come from?**

**Could you please share your lights with me ?**

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try using your browser developer tools to see whether there are any script errors occurring.
2. It looks like you might be using a custom master page? If so, try changing to the standard master page to see if the error goes away, that would then indicate an issue with the master page.

Comment: Hello Paul,
First of all, thank you for your time.
1. Yes, we did watch the console and the debugger to see if something was happening but no, it is not. 2. I have rebuilt a new Site Collection under the same domain. It is a standard one, publihing portal, with no custom at all. The bug do not appear. Regarding your answer, i tried to apply the custom masterpage to this new collection, and the bug does not appear either. So it is not custom master page that causes the trouble.
If you have any other ideas..

Comment: Hello @PaulLucas : 
We tried further and found that our Ribbon div has an attribute "unselectable" set to "on", so the ribbon is greyish.
Do you know why has SP set this ? And how to change it ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure, maybe you could try to create a separate site collection to see if the issue happens there as well.